# Linux find command: weird behavior

Tags: linux, find

Why do the results of these three find commands are different, depending on what directory I am in?

```
daniel@machine:~$ find /home/daniel/workspace/service/tests/smoke -name *.test
(result: lists all files named *.test as expected)

daniel@machine:~/workspace$ find /home/daniel/workspace/service/tests/smoke -name *.test
find: paths must precede expression: service_real_all_tests_possible.test
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]

daniel@dtrezub:~/workspace/service$ find /home/daniel/workspace/service/tests/smoke -name *.test
/home/daniel/workspace/service/tests/smoke/doc.test
```

Comment: Because you didn't quote the `*` so your shell expands it first.

Comment: Try [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net), it points out a lot of shell weirdness like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote name like this

```
find /home/daniel/workspace/service/tests/smoke -name "*.test"
```

Otherwise, shell is doing glob expansion.

Answer (score 0):

The different behaviour depends on how many files in the current dir (not subdirs) match `*.test`.

```
0 matches => find command is executed like you intended
1 match   => find command will only look for files with the same name as the *.test in your current dir.
>1 match  => Your find command is incorrect 
# ignoring special cases like a filename `-name something.test`
```

Fix: Put `*.test` in quotes or write `\*.test`.